# VS 2005 SSIS Error value origin

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

I have an ssis package created in vs 2005 that has started to give me the following error:

[Lawson Staging Table [4046]] Error: There was an error with input column "JOB_CODE" (4200) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (4059). The column status returned was: "The value violated 
the integrity constraints for the column.".

My first question is: what are the 4046, 4200 & 4059 values following my table, column and destination?

My second question is about the integrity constraint message.  The destination table is a heap (no keys or indexes) with no constraints. The destination column is defined as a varchar(10). The input column is from oracle, is defined as char(9) and is called job_code.  So - where is there an integrity constraint defined?

The final question is about the select statement; looks like the following:

```
Select ...
,lpad(trim(e.job_code),10,'0') as job_code ...
```

If I take the lpad and trim functions out, it works but I need these functions in place because my spec calls for a fixed length column padded with leading zeros.  This column returns data as expected in TOAD but fails in the ssis package.  Does anyone see an issue with how the functions are being used?

Since this package worked in the past but suddenly started to throw this error, I'm assuming that new invalid data has come into play. however, recently added rows don't seem to be any different then historical records.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are more likely to be the ids assigned to the each task/table/column etc.
You could probably go to the advanced editor of the data flow task and look at the input and output properties. You can see that for each input or for each column there is an ID assigned.

Next: The error that you are getting occurs usually when "Allow Nulls" option is unchecked.

```
    Try this:
    Look at the name of the column for this error/warning.
    Go to SSMS and find the table
    Allow Nulls for that Column
    Save the table
    Rerun the SSIS
```

Comment: I did check the advanced editor and the numbers don't match up.

Comment: Setting the destination col to allow nulls worked - that was the integrity constraint.  However, the origination column is defined as JOB_CODE NOT NULL CHAR(9) so I'm still not sure how nulls are getting passed into the destination column.  Something has to be wrong with the way I'm using the lpad or trim functions.